# Call external URL from android and get response

Tags: android, url, call

I am trying to call a URL in android using

```
HttpClient mClient= new DefaultHttpClient()

HttpGet get = new HttpGet("www.google.com ");

mClient.execute(get);

HttpResponse res = mClient.execute(get);
```

But, I did not get any response. How can I call URL in Android?

Comment: You are missing a semicolon `;` in your first line.

Answer (score 7):

This is a complete example:

```
        DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(yourURL);
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
        String line = "";
        String NL = System.getProperty("line.separator");
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {                    
            sb.append(line + NL);
        }
        in.close();
        String result = sb.toString();
        Log.v("My Response :: ", result);
```

use the url with the protocol "`https://`"

```
"https://www.stackoverflow.com" instead of just "www.stackoverflow.com"
```

be sure to have this permission into your `androidmanifest.xml`

```
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: Post a copy of your log output if you can. Also ensure your app has the uses_internet permission set in the manifest.

Comment: For newer Android versions, you need to use https or make exceptions as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50834600/2738240
Otherwise you will get errors (see Run/Debug log in Android Studio).

Answer (score 3):

You must add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>` in the AndroidManifest.xml file. Under `<manifest>` element.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `mClient.execute(get)` twice.

```
mClient.execute(get);
HttpResponse res = mClient.execute(get);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use volley instead.

```
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    String getUrl = "http://www.google.com";
    StringRequest getRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, getUrl, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse (String response) {
            Log.v(TAG, "GET response: " + response);
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse (VolleyError error) {
            Log.v(TAG, "Volley GET error: " + error.getMessage());
        }
    });
    requestQueue.add(getRequest);
```