# Getting number of likes a Facebook page has

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk

I would like to know if there is a simple method for retrieving the number of Facebook likes a Facebook page has.

Would it be in my best interest using the Facebook SDK? Or would such a simple operation be achievable via other methods?

If anyone has any guidance for me, it would be much appreciated if you shared it with me, thanks.

Comment: I've been wondering what would be the best method to achieve what I want to do, so I haven't tried anything so far.

Comment: Just been looking around on https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/ mainly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For that basic info, you don´t need to use the Facebook SDK. You just need to retrieve the data of the following URL: `http://graph.facebook.com/[vanity-url or page-id]/`

Put that in the browser and you will see which information you can get.

Comment: How can I now use that data? I would just like to get the number of likes presented from https://graph.facebook.com/JeniferOfficiel?fields=likes and make it into a usable string in my app?

Comment: i am afraid i can´t help you there, my knowledge in android development is limited to phonegap and stuff. in javascript, you could do an ajax call to get the result as json. maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4889618/call-external-url-from-android-and-get-response